# How to get random values using a dictionary to associate the ranges

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm stuck on an issue with random number ranges.

I have 4 values and a dictionary with a range of random numbers:

```
import random

val1 = 1
val2 = 1
val3 = 2
val4 = 3

dict_num = {1: random.randrange(1, 10),
        2: random.randrange(10, 20),
        3: random.randrange(20, 30)}

for key in dict_num :
    if key == val1:
        out1 = dict_num [key]
    if key == val2:
        out2 = dict_num [key]

print(out1, out2)

# Output
  5 5
```

I thought this would've been a clean approach but my issue comes if any of the val variables have the same value, the outputs are the same. The random value gets associated with the key and doesn't change. Is there a better approach so that each val will have its own random number?

I appreciate any advice, Thank you!

Comment: what did You expect if the `val` variables are the same?

Comment: What do you mean by " each val will have its own random number"? In your dictionary the "1" is mapped to a range of random numbers. So for val = 1 what is the expected behaviour? If there are multiple keys with the same value, do you want to generate different random number ranges for them?

Comment: @GaneshTata Yes, I'm trying to get a different random number for each of the val variables. So even though val1 and val2 are both = 1, they'd pull their own random value from the range 1 to 10. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Matiiss I was hoping they'd be able to pull their own random number from the range 1 to 10 but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a better approach:

```py
import random


value_dct = {'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 2, 'value4': 3}

range_dct = {1: [1, 10],
             2: [10, 20],
             3: [20, 30]}

for key, value in value_dct.items():
    value_dct[key] = random.randrange(range_dct[value][0], range_dct[value][1])

print(value_dct)
```

First of store those values in a dictionary so that way it will be easier to access them in a loop, also don't call the `randrange` immediately because it will set those values, instead just specify the range and when assigning range to the value call the `randrange` function.

To access those values You could for example use: `value_dct['value1']` and this will give You the value.

Comment: Thank you for the better approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the random number ranges as a tuple in the dictionary and call the `random.randrange` function inside the for loop. Note - Do not use `dict` as a variable name since it is a keyword in python.

```
import random

val1 = 1
val2 = 1
val3 = 2
val4 = 3

randomval_mapping = 
        {1: (1,10),
        2: (10,20),
        3: (20,30)}

for key in randomval_mapping:
    lower, upper = randomval_mapping[key]
    if key == val1:
        random_val = random.randrange(lower, upper)
        print(key, random_val)
    if key == val2:
        random_val = random.randrange(lower, upper)
        print(key, random_val)
    else:
        random_val = random.randrange(lower, upper)
```

Output -

```
1 9
1 8
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mason Do consider the approach in Matiiss answer since it is an elegant way to approach this problem.